# Combine Similar Items in Collection

Tags: c#, list, collections, nested

I have a collection of products inside a collection of an area inside of a designset which is inside a job, I have a lot of nested collections.

The problem is that I have multiple of the same products, with different ids, that I need to combine into one, so that someone looking at a paper will make less mistakes and they can just look at the quantity.

So, I need to combine the products, but really I just need to delete any products with the same name and add their quantity to the quantity of the one that is not deleted.

I am able to get a list of all the ones I need to delete, unfortunately that list also includes the ones I don't want to delete.

Here is what I have so far:

I get a list of products

```
var ds = j.DesignSets;

IList<Product> productsList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Product>();

foreach(var dsa in ds)
{
    foreach(var p in dsa.DesignSetAreas)
    {
        foreach(var pr in p.Products)
        {
            if(pr.ProductMods.Count == 0)
            {
                if(pr.DeliveryCnt == 0)
                {
                    productsList.Add(pr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I loop through everything again but this time I create another list inside the deignset to list the products I am going to delete.

I also loop through the previously created list to see if I have any products with the same displayName.

```
foreach(var dsa in ds)
{
    var deleteProducts = new List<Product>();

    foreach(var p in dsa.DesignSetAreas)
    {
        foreach(var pr in p.Products)
        {
            if(pr.ProductMods.Count == 0)
            {
                if(pr.DeliveryCnt == 0)
                {
                    var partQuantity = 0;
                    var partAmount = 0;

                    foreach(var product in productsList)
                    {
                        if(pr.Display == product.Display)
                        {
                            partQuantity = partQuantity + product.Quantity;

                            partAmount++;

                            pr.Quantity = partQuantity;
                        }
                    }

                    if(partAmount >= 2)
                    {
                        deleteProducts.Add(pr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(var item in deleteProducts)
        {
            p.Products.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Besides being a mess this code adds all the products with the same name then it deletes them.

I don't really mind if the code is a mess, I am going to try to clean it up, as long as I can get it working I don't really mind. Though if you have suggestions for how to clean this up I would appreciate it.

So, for the question.

How do I get this code to delete all but one of the products with the same name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used classes to simulate you mess.  Then applied Linq :

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database j = new Database();

            var ds = j.DesignSets;

            List<Product> productsList = ds.Select(dsa => dsa.DesignSetAreas.Select(p => p.Products.Where(pr => (pr.ProductMods.Count == 0) && (pr.DeliveryCnt == 0))).SelectMany(x => x)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
            var productNames = productsList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Database
    {
        public List<DesignSet> DesignSets { get; set; }
    }
    public class DesignSet
    {
        public List<DesignSetArea> DesignSetAreas { get; set; }
    }
    public class DesignSetArea
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public List<string> ProductMods { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryCnt { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```